# case insensitive search in polars python

Tags: python-polars

How to perform case insensitive search in polars python,

```
pdf.filter(pl.col("REFERENCE_2").str.contains("search string"))
```

want to search string "Search String or Search string"

similar like pandas

```
pdf.filter(pl.col("REFERENCE_2").str.contains("search string", case=False))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.contains`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.contains.html#polars.Expr.str.contains) takes a regex pattern.

Inside a regex you can use `(?i)` to turn on case-insensitive matching.

```
>>> df.select(pl.col("col").str.contains(r"(?i)search string"))
shape: (4, 1)
┌───────┐
│ col   │
│ ---   │
│ bool  │
╞═══════╡
│ true  │
│ true  │
│ false │
│ false │
└───────┘
```

`(?-i)` can be used to turn it off, which allows you to only apply it to a specific part of your pattern.

```
>>> df.select(pl.col("col").str.contains("(?i)SEARCH(?-i) string"))
shape: (4, 1)
┌───────┐
│ col   │
│ ---   │
│ bool  │
╞═══════╡
│ false │
│ true  │
│ false │
│ false │
└───────┘
```

Supported regex syntax: https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#grouping-and-flags

Dataframe used:

```
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({"col": ["seARch StRInG", "search string", "search", "string"]})
>>> df
shape: (4, 1)
┌───────────────┐
│ col           │
│ ---           │
│ str           │
╞═══════════════╡
│ seARch StRInG │
│ search string │
│ search        │
│ string        │
└───────────────┘
```